# Node Name not showing in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using a FOREACH and note that X and Y Nodes are filled in but do not show on database display in neo4j.

[image: Empty Display for Nodes]

Values are set and correct.

Puzzled as to why. Simple code to generate Nodes and the various Relationship Types from a csv.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/neo4j_module_datasets/test2.csv" AS line

MERGE (X:MyNodeX{text: line.X})
MERGE (Y:MyNodeY{text: line.Y})

   FOREACH (w in SPLIT(line.A, " ") |
      MERGE (X)–[R:REL {relationship: w}]->(Y))
```

Comment: I noted I needed to set caption values? But why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The browser visualizer is distinct from neo4j itself, and the visualizer has no way of knowing which properties on your nodes of a specific label to use for display, so the process for selection is manual.

To set the caption, first click on the node label whose caption you want to change (located at the top of your visualization). This will show display options at the bottom of the visualization, such as color, size, and caption, where the caption options are the properties of nodes of that label. Clicking on one of those caption options will change all nodes of that label to use that property for the caption.

Comment: Thanks, but in some cases it is set default wise. I was not sure why not in this case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not aware of any defaults, that doesn't really make sense when properties are entirely user defined. If you mean auto-selection of some property to use as a caption, then yes, that usually happens, and I don't know the cases where it would not happen, as in your scenario. You may find the [documentation on the browser interface](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/) helpful, there is advanced caption handling in there if you search for it.